# Error when trying to execute a simple command in Android activity

Tags: java, android

I am learning to read and write simple files using Android apps written in Java. But I am not able to resolve this initial error! I think I am getting this error because of `this` in place of context. The app is compiling successfully but it is not opening after installing in my device.

I have not tried much but I am providing the code here. I am trying to accept a simple text through edit text view and then saving it to a file in Android using the button save.

```
package com.example.filemaketest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String filename = "Testing-app-file.txt";
    File path = this.getFilesDir();

    //    File file = new File(path, filename);
//    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    public void save(View view) {
        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.infoText);
        String info = edit.getText().toString();
        Log.i("info", info);
        Toast.makeText(this, info + " button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, " Saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        try {
//            outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, this.MODE_PRIVATE);
//            outputStream.write(info.getBytes());
//            outputStream.close();
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Could you add the crash information from Logcat into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that springs out to me is this line:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String filename ="Testing-app-file.txt";
    File path= this.getFilesDir();           // <<< This line
```

You are defining `path` inline within the class definition, which is equivalent to setting it within the `MainActivity()` constructor. This is before the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) has begun, therefore `this` as a `Context` does not exist yet. You will need to define `path` later on in the activity lifecycle, for example during `onCreate()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String filename ="Testing-app-file.txt";
    File path;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        path = this.getFilesDir();
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for help and precious time . It worked for me, at least my app is not crashing and there are no errors.But I am not able to confirm that whether the file is being created or not in my android mobile . Can you please suggest me some solution?

Comment: @AryanAgarwal That's probably best asked as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), to keep this current question tidy as a reference to others who may encounter this error in future.